# PHP MySQL filtering results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently building a script for a radio station and need help with the following script:

```
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);
$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

What that's suppose to do is return the previous day's timetable from 00:00 to 23:00. However at the moment it's only returning it from 01:00 to 23:00. Is there any way I could make the 00:00 get be included?

Comment: Obvious thing first.  Is there actually a row where time is 0000?

Comment: Tough.  It doesn't look like anything is wrong.  Try putting up the code that displays the result.  That may help.

Comment: @dunsmoreb that's a bit more complex, it then runs it into a script which turns it into an RSS feed....

Comment: Can you try it in just a MySQL query browser? If that works then something has to be wrong with the display code, or the code that runs through `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change timezone before receiving $yesterday using `date_default_timezone_set` with necessary timezone.

e.g. date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Comment: What about this one: $yesterday = strtotime('yesterday') - 3600;
Are you sure, that you have data with 00:00?